# How can I make my chart's axes use the same proportions for scaling?

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

Using Chart.js, I have made a scatter plot. The points on the chart will always be on an axis. Currently, I am using the following options and data:

```
public scatterChartLabels:string[] = ['Experiencing', 'Ideation', 'Thinking', 'Evaluation'];

public scatterChartData = [
    {
      x: 0,
      y: localStorage.getItem('col1')
    }, {
      x: localStorage.getItem('col2'),
      y: 0
    }, {
      x: 0,
      y:  - localStorage.getItem('col3')
    },
    {
      x: - localStorage.getItem('col4'),
      y: 0
    },
    {
      x: 0,
      y: localStorage.getItem('col1')
    }
  ]

  public scatterChartOptions = {
    showLines: true,
    yAxes: {
      gridLines: {
        zeroLineWidth: 100
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          zeroLineColor: '#c1272d'
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          zeroLineColor: '#c1272d'
        }
      }],
    }
  }

  public scatterChartType: string = 'scatter';

  public scatterChartCustomColors = [{
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 147, 29, 0.5)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 147, 29)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 147, 29, 0.5)',
    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)'
  }]
```

This produces the following chart:

[image]

How can I make the chart use the same scale on both axes? For example, If the highest y-axis value is 130, how can I make the lowest y-axis tick 130, and the x-axis ticks -130 and 130?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by updating the tick settings for each axis:

```
public scatterChartOptions = {
    ...
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min : - 130,
          max : 130
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min : - 130,
          max : 130
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```